# How can we sort the words inside a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

In my postgresql table one column data is like below

```
250 TABLETS + PVC + PVDC + ALU + HOSPITAL PACK + Film-coated tablet - BLISTER - [/Tablet] - QUETIAPINE FUMARATE 28.78 mg is present 
20 ML + MATERIAL UNKNOWN + Oral suspension - BOTTLE - [/mL] - ALUMINIUM HYDROXIDE 37 mg; MAGNESIUM HYDROXIDE 40 mg...
```

How can I split this string based on '+' character and sort this alphabetically and put `|` character and update the same column?

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: regexp_split_to_array -> unnest -> ORDER BY -> string_agg

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table has some ID column, you can get it this way:

```
with ct as
(
select id,
  unnest(regexp_split_to_array(t, '\+')) part
from
  a
), 
ct2 as
(
select
  id, string_agg(part, '|' order by part) parts
from
  ct
group by
  id
)
update a
set t = ct2.parts
from ct2
where ct2.id = a.id;
```

> ```
> id | t                                                                                                                                  
> -: | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | 250 TABLETS | ALU | Film-coated tablet - BLISTER - [/Tablet] - QUETIAPINE FUMARATE 28.78 mg is present| HOSPITAL PACK | PVC | PVDC 
>  2 | 20 ML | MATERIAL UNKNOWN | Oral suspension - BOTTLE - [/mL] - ALUMINIUM HYDROXIDE 37 mg; MAGNESIUM HYDROXIDE 40 mg
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05e8041e58a97a500b27fae8d16456b7)*